# Issue with globally assigned string variables in C#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, global-variables

Please see the below C# code.

```
 string file_name;

 if (Directory.GetFiles(targetPath, "*.xls").Length != 0)
        {
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\INTEL_ADMIN\Downloads\SubDir");
                var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
                          orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                          select f).First();


                file_name = myFile.Name;
        }

 MessageBox.Show(file_name);
```

I have initialized the String `file_name` globally and initializing the value inside the `if else` block and trying to retrieve the same value outside the block. I am getting the below `Build Error`. Can you please explain why..?

`Usage of unassigned local variable file_name`

Comment: You need to initialize the variable properly : `string file_name = null` , because compiler has to be assured with guaranteed initialization, in your case its not guaranteed as incase of  if condition fails.

Comment: Change it to `string file_name = string.Empty;`

Comment: string file_name = "";

Comment: Side note: I suspect you use "globally" in very unusual way... In most cases this word used to describe class level variables (fields) instance or static... Code sample seem to show regular local variable... Try to read a C# book/article to use more standard words when asking questions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank u for ur suggestion...

Comment: Also, while you declare file_name at the top you give it a value within an if statement. So it may or may not have been initialized when you called MessageBox.Show which is why the compiler complained.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not initialized automatically.
Use

```
string file_name = string.Empty;
```